# How to Identify HTML attributes (Web Scraping)

Tags: html, c++, web, web-scraping, attributes

**I'm building a web scraper and I am at a loss for how to discern element attributes.**

Currently, I'm moving a "scanning head" from left to write across the code, and I look for certain character strings to flag an attribute. For example, up until this point, I look for `="` to decide where an attribute may exist.

Problems have started arising though, because there are multiple "valid" ways to write HTML.

For example, from [this home depot page](https://www.homedepot.com/p/RYOBI-20-in-40-Volt-6-0-Ah-Lithium-Ion-Battery-Brushless-Cordless-Walk-Behind-Self-Propelled-Lawn-Mower-with-Charger-Included-RY401120-Y/311084824), the source code has two particular elements:

```html
<a href="https://www.homedepot.com/b/Featured-Products-Ryobi/N-5yc1vZ1z18hrf?cm_sp=vanity-_-ryobi-_-APR19" target="_blank" style="color:#F96302;">Learn More about the RYOBI Platform Here</a>
<a href=https://www.homedepot.com/c/electronics_recycling_programs style=color:#F96302; target=_blank>Click here for more information on Electronic Recycling Programs</a>
```

**This causes a headache for the scraper**. The first element scrapes, but the second element does not have any `="` to find. I can't just look for `=` neither, because that would give false positives, like in the first element there is `...sp=vanity...` which wouldn't parse correctly.

**How can I handle these multiple syntaxes of HTML?**

**Edit: I have been using C++ up to this point**

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Right, Thanks, C++ is what i"m using

Answer (score 0):

**Postulated answer**

I have a thought but I'm not sure yet how well it will work. I could try pulling substrings based on the whitespaces `" "` then look for the first instance of an `=`

**For example:**

`<a href="foo" target="bar">` -> pull substrings based on `" "` to get **attList**: `['href="foo"', 'target="bar"']`

Then `foreach(string att, attList)`, set `key = att.left(att.indexOf('='))` and `value = att.right(att.indexOf('='))`